# Arbitrary command completion - possible?

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a way to hook in a custom bash completion function. Problem is, I want this completion function not just for a specific command, but for all commands.

Is this even possible? Having looked around for a while, I couldn't find any resources online.

To reduce the problem to the most trivial case: would it be possible to always have tab-completion for the string 'foo'?

Meaning `echo f<tab>` would expand into `echo foo`, and `ls fo<tab>` would expand into `ls foo`

For context: I'm trying to implement something similar to http://blog.plenz.com/2012-01/zsh-complete-words-from-tmux-pane.html in bash, but I'm starting to fear it's not possible.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?  http://superuser.com/questions/327401/is-there-a-windows-command-line-with-smart-bash-like-autocompletions-command-h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with the `-D` option of the `complete` command:

```
suggest_hello()
{   
    COMPREPLY=( hello )
    return 0
}

complete -D -F suggest_hello
```

Now whenever I type `echo h<Tab>`, I get `echo hello`.

```
$ help complete
complete: ...
...
      -D  apply the completions and actions as the default for commands
          without any specific completion defined
...
```

Comment: Note that this will collide with bash-completion, so you'd have to choose which one to use.

Comment: @geirha is there a way to merge results?

Comment: @jbnicolai: to merge the results, you can add `-o bashdefault` to all the bash-completions, or you can write a function that intelligently merges the results. Neither solutions are ideal, but that's how Bash works.

Comment: @jbnicolai well, bash-completion defines its own default completion (`complete -D`) which tries to look up completion for the current command and use that if it exists, else it falls back to a default. You'd have to hook into that.